# pytorch static quantization: different training(calibration) and inference backends

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, quantization-aware-training

Can we use a different CPU architecture(and backend) for training(calibration) and inference of the quantized pytorch model?

The [only post on this subject that I've found](https://spell.ml/blog/pytorch-quantization-X8e7wBAAACIAHPhT) states:

> **static quantization must be performed on a machine with the same
> architecture as your deployment target.** If you are using FBGEMM, you
> must perform the calibration pass on an x86 CPU; if you are using
> QNNPACK, calibration needs to happen on an ARM CPU

But there is nothing about this in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The information in the link you posted is correct. You should use the same backend in both the cases. This is also mentioned in the official documentation-

"When preparing a quantized model, it is necessary to ensure that qconfig and the engine used for quantized computations match the backend on which the model will be executed."

Find it here

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/quantization.html

Comment: So, they talk about `qconfig` and `engine`, both of these are configuration options. But state nothing about the `backend` of the machine used for training/calibration.